# $\binom{an}{bn}\equiv 0\pmod{pn-1}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Recently I think on the following conjecture of binomial coefficient:

‎There are no positive integers $a>b$ such that‎

‎$\binom{an}{bn}\equiv 0\pmod{pn-1}$
‎for all $n\geqslant 1$‎.

I could prove this conjecture for the special cause $\gcd(a,p)=1$. I proved the following theorem:

Theorem:
‎There are no positive integers $a>b$ with $\gcd(a,p)=1$ such that‎

‎$\binom{an}{bn}\equiv 0\pmod{pn-1}$
‎for all $n\geqslant 1$‎.
‎

Proof:‎Suppose on the contrary that $a>b$ exist satisfying the conditions of the theorem‎. ‎Let $a=a'p-a_0$ and $b=b'p+b_0$ such that $0\leq a_0,b_0<p$‎, ‎and $a',b'\geq0$‎. ‎Clearly‎, ‎$a+a'-1\geq b+b'$‎. ‎Let $n\geq 2a$ be such that $q_n:=pn-1$ is a prime (whose existence is guaranteed by Dirichlet's theorem)‎. ‎If $m_n:=pn+n-1$‎, ‎then $q_n(p+1)=pm_n-1$ divides $\binom{am_n}{bm_n}$‎. ‎On the other hand‎, ‎
‎‎
‎\begin{align*}‎
‎\binom{am_n}{bm_n}&=\binom{a(pn+n-1)}{b(pn+n-1)}\\‎
‎&=\binom{(a+a'-1)q_n+nq_n-a_0n+a'}{(b+b')q_n+b_0n+b'}\\‎
‎&\equiv\binom{a+a'-1}{b+b'}\binom{nq_n-a_0n+a'}{b_0n+b'}\\‎
‎&\equiv\binom{a+a'-1}{b+b'}\binom{-a_0n+a'}{b_0n+b'}\not\equiv0\pmod{q_n}‎
‎\end{align*}‎
‎by Lucas's theorem‎, ‎which is a contradiction‎.

I think prove of this conjecture for generl case is very hard and actully I have no idea for prove it.

I would be happy if I know your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find this interesting ? ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem

Comment: This problem is different with  Wolstenholme's theorem. How can I use the Wolstenholme's theorem for proof of this problem?